# Add Button on wordpress search result page

Tags: wordpress, search, wordpress-theming, customization, custom-wordpress-pages

i want to add a button "Sneaker Not found? Click Here" in search result case. this button will work as link to another page where customer can submit custom order.please tell me where i have to code for this button.

i have try to add button code in search.php but button not appear in search result page

"

```
        <?php if ( $postCount > 8 ) { ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="search-form-wrapper u-mb-30">
                        <div class="search gensearch__wrapper kl-gensearch--<?php echo zget_option( 'zn_main_style', 'color_options', false, 'light' ); ?>">
                            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12"> 
                <a class="btn" href="">Not found Desired Sneakers? Click here</a>
                </div>

                </div>
</section>
```

"

Comment: share your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise, it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help you to improve your question. Good luck!

Comment: i have added code , please help me now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a default WordPress search page you can access the number of results via the global wp_query.

```
global $wp_query;

$customOrderPageId = 10; // UPDATE with your custom order page ID
$searchTerm = get_search_query() // If you want a flexible "Desired Sneakers" based on what the user is searching...

if ($wp_query->found_posts == 0) {
 echo '<a class="btn" href="'.get_permalink($customOrderPageId).'">Not found '.$searchTerm.'? Click here</a>';
}
```